# Aspose cloud support for aws and azure

Tags: aspose

Team,
Couple of questions on Aspose Cloud product:

- Does Aspose cloud provide support for AWS cloud (Amazon) and Azure cloud (Microsoft) platforms
- Requirement is to read and modify hyperlinks of text documents (word, excel, powerpoint, text files, pdf, htmls etc.,) located in AWS and Azure cloud platforms using Aspose cloud APIs (.net APIS) programatically. More especially, accessing files from AWS CVO and Azure Netapp ?

Kindly, clarify.

Comment: Team salutation? Also, you might want to check it out over Aspose Cloud documentation and support or simply search related queries over the internet for quicker results.

Comment: Please stop writing anything in all caps. That's considered SHOUTING.

Comment: @harshit Gupta, I couldn’t find one

Comment: @RaghavendarKannan you may check [documentation](https://docs.aspose.cloud/total/getting-started/dashboard/how-to-configure-3rd-party-cloud-storages/) to use Aspose Cloud APIs with third party storages. Otherwise, can post your query in aspose.cloud forums.

Comment: @Tilal Ahmad, could you pl share links for posting queries with aspose pls… ? I couldn’t find any